# Creating PHP analytics for each user profile

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create analytic data for each of the User Profiles by telling them how many visitors visited from city & country visited their profile.

This is what I'm currently doing.

```
session_start();

$analyticsuser = $_SESSION["analyticsuser"];

if($analyticsuser!=$author) //$author is where the id of each profile is stored.
{        
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
    $query = @unserialize(file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/php/'.$ip));
    if($query && $query['status'] == 'success') 
    {
        $userip = $query['query'];
        $usercountry = $query ['country'];
        $usercity = $query['city'];

        $connection = mysqli_connect("HOSTNAME","USERNAME","PASSWORD","leo_site") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));
        $sqlanalytics = "INSERT INTO member_analytics VALUES(NULL,\"$userip\",\"$author\",\"$usercity\",\"$usercountry\",now());";
        $resanalytics = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlanalytics) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    } 
    else {    echo 'Unable to get location';    }
}    

$_SESSION["analyticsuser"] = $author;
```

I'm trying to get how many visitors visited their profile from different city & countries.

The problem I'm facing now is, if I visit a profile again after visiting another profile, the data is still recorded. This should not happen as we have already recorded the visitor for that profile.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to solve this issue, one of them which I mostly used is an feature of mysql. 
First create a composite key using author and userip.
After that at place of insert run replace query. As per nature of replace query if its find same author and userip combination field it replace that row by new data and if there is no combination found it will insert it.

```
$sqlanalytics = "REPLACE INTO member_analytics VALUES(NULL,\"$userip\",\"$author\",\"$usercity\",\"$usercountry\",now());";
```

Comment: I'm trying to get how many visitors visited their profile from different city & countries. Sql is working fine, its le logic im confused.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem, You have to read session ID to check everytime if a profile is already visited by a visitor.

Below is the correct code.

```
session_start();

$new_sessionid = session_id();

$connection = mysqli_connect("HOSTNAME","USERNAME","PASSWORD","leo_site") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));
$sqlcanalytics = "SELECT * FROM member_analytics WHERE sessid=\"$new_sessionid\" AND uid=\"$author\";";
$rescanalytics = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlcanalytics) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));
$numcanalytics = mysqli_num_rows($rescanalytics);
if($numcanalytics==0)
{
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
    $query = @unserialize(file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/php/'.$ip));
    if($query && $query['status'] == 'success') 
    {
        $userip = $query['query'];
        $userisp = $query['isp'];
        $organization = $query['org'];
        $usercountry = $query ['country'];
        $userregion = $query['regionName'];
        $usercity = $query['city'];

        $sqlanalytics = "INSERT INTO member_analytics VALUES(NULL,\"$userip\",\"$author\",\"$new_sessionid\",\"$usercity\",\"$usercountry\",now());";
        $resanalytics = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlanalytics) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));
    } 
    else { echo 'Unable to get location'; }
}
```

Thanks for the help!